# nodejs usage of globals

Tags: node.js, parameters, lambda

I am new to NodeJS, but a pretty experienced programmer. I am working on a side project to get my feet wet with node. I am looking at MongoDB for storage. To get started I just wanted to test creating some basic CRUD functions in node. I have included my code below.

My question is regarding the global var 'updated'. It is used in the 'read' and 'update' functions to control which function gets called next. I would like to call them in the following order: create, read, update, read, delete.

It is my understanding that I cannot pass in a function parameter to 'read' to dictate which function to call next because this is called asynchronously and the lambda function I am defining as my callback to mongojs.read will not have the parent functions parameters to use.

What is the correct way to do this? Using a global feels like a hack. :)

```
// app.js
//<user>:<password>@<server>/<database>
var connection = "foo:bar@127.0.0.1/blah";
var collections = ["scores"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(connection, collections);
//console.log(db);

var updated = false;

function my_create()
{
    console.log("my_create");
    db.leaderboard.save({name: "sunder", score: 42}, function(err, result) {
          if(err || !result ) 
          {
              console.log("Score save failed");
              console.log(err);
          }
          else
          {
              console.log("Score save successful");
              my_read();
          }
    });
}

function my_read()
{
    console.log("my_read");
    // app.js
    db.leaderboard.find({name: "sunder"}, function(err, results) {
        if(err || !results)
        {
            console.log("Score read failed");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else 
        {
            results.forEach(function(score) 
            {
                console.log(score);
            });

            // I am sure using globals is a HACK. Need to figure this out. 
            if(updated)
                my_delete();
            else
                my_update();
        }
    });

}

function my_update()
{
    console.log("my_update");
    db.leaderboard.update({name: "sunder"}, {$set: {score: 1337}}, function(err,     result) {
        if(err || !result) 
        {
            console.log("Score update failed");
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Score update successful");

            updated = true;
            my_read();
        }
    });
}

function my_delete()
{
    console.log("my_delete");
    db.leaderboard.remove({name: "sunder"}, function(err, result) {
        if(err || !result) 
        {
            console.log("Score delete failed");
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Score delete successful");
            process.exit();
        }
    });
}

// kick off the flow of processes
my_create();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the next action to perform into the `my_read()` function like this:

```
// app.js
var connection = "foo:bar@127.0.0.1/blah";
var collections = ["scores"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(connection, collections);

function my_create()
{
    console.log("my_create");
    db.leaderboard.save({name: "sunder", score: 42}, function(err, result) {
          if(err || !result ) 
          {
              console.log("Score save failed");
              console.log(err);
          }
          else
          {
              console.log("Score save successful");
              my_read("update");
          }
    });
}

function my_read(next_action)
{
    console.log("my_read");
    // app.js
    db.leaderboard.find({name: "sunder"}, function(err, results) {
        if(err || !results)
        {
            console.log("Score read failed");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else 
        {
            results.forEach(function(score) 
            {
                console.log(score);
            });

            // I am sure using globals is a HACK. Need to figure this out. 
            if(next_action === "delete")
                my_delete();
            else
                my_update();
        }
    });

}

function my_update()
{
    console.log("my_update");
    db.leaderboard.update({name: "sunder"}, {$set: {score: 1337}}, function(err,     result) {
        if(err || !result) 
        {
            console.log("Score update failed");
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Score update successful");

            updated = true;
            my_read("delete");
        }
    });
}

function my_delete()
{
    console.log("my_delete");
    db.leaderboard.remove({name: "sunder"}, function(err, result) {
        if(err || !result) 
        {
            console.log("Score delete failed");
        }
        else 
        {
            console.log("Score delete successful");
            process.exit();
        }
    });
}

// kick off the flow of processes
my_create();
```